# Which field is "Case Article Title" in CaseArticle Object?

Tags: visualforce, soql, case

I am creating a VF Page where I need "Case Article Title" but I am not able to identify which field i have to query from CaseArticle. I need to show the encircled value in the below image. [image]

Answer (score 1):

So the `CaseArticle` object really just relates knowledge objects to the `Case`. The real object in question is `KnowledgeArticleVersion`. You would have query each `Article Type` separately, for example:

```
SELECT Title FROM FAQ__kav
WHERE Id IN (
    SELECT KnowledgeArticleVersionId FROM CaseArticle
    WHERE CaseId = '<some_case_id>'
)
```